# Where should I ask a question about studying?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

My question is:

> What should I teach that would be great to know about qt framework?

Where should it be asked?

Comment: Nowhere on the Stack Exchange network, I'm afraid. Stack Exchange is not big on questions where the answers are suggestions (leading to a theoretically unlimited number of answers, and subjective ones at that) rather than technical, specifically answerable Q&A

Comment: ["We already tried supporting those questions, we even gave them their own site. Sadly, it didn't work out..."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200144/165773)

Comment: While you can't ask the question here, popular tags often have site and book recommendations in the tag info that are good resources.

Comment: @BSMP as github also have, in many languages even and all of them for *free*.

Answer (score 16):

Maybe Reddit or Quora, but not a Q&A site in the Stack Exchange network. This question is too broad and too opinion-based to fit on Stack Overflow or any other site here. From the [blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/):

> **What kind of questions should I not ask here?**
>
> Avoid asking questions that are subjective, argumentative, or require extended discussion. This is not a discussion board, this is a place for questions that can be answered!

Comment: can i ask a question related to frameworks like which is better to use? can i ask it here?

Comment: Nope, same story.

Comment: So can you suggest where to ask or Stack overflow didn't help for this type of question? @Glorfindel

Comment: Yes, Reddit or Quora. It just doesn't work on a strict Q&A focused on objective content like Stack Exchange.

Comment: now my confusion is clear. Thanks